# Reshaping Pytorch tensor

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, pytorch

I have a tensor of size `(24, 2, 224, 224)` in Pytorch.

- 24 = batch size
- 2 = matrixes representing foreground and
  background
- 224 = image height dimension
- 224 = image width
  dimension

This is the output of a CNN that performs binary segmentation. In each cell of the 2 matrixes is stored the probability for that pixel to be foreground or background: `[n][0][h][w] + [n][1][h][w] = 1` for every coordinate

I want to reshape it into a tensor of size `(24, 1, 224, 224)`. The values in the new layer should be `0` or `1` according to the matrix in which the probability was higher.

How can I do that? Which function should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`torch.argmax()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.argmax) (for PyTorch +0.4):

```
prediction = torch.argmax(tensor, dim=1) # with 'dim' the considered dimension 
prediction = prediction.unsqueeze(1) # to reshape from (24, 224, 224) to (24, 1, 224, 224)
```

---

If the PyTorch version is below 0.4.0, one can use [`tensor.max()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.max) which returns both the max values and their indices (but which isn't differentiable over the index values):

```
_, prediction = tensor.max(dim=1)
prediction = prediction.unsqueeze(1) # to reshape from (24, 224, 224) to (24, 1, 224, 224)
```

Comment: Running your code I get the following error:

    **AttributeError: module ‘torch’ has no attribute ‘argmax’**.

That’s very strange, I’ve used torch.argmax before. Something obvious that I’m missing?

Comment: I would assume the error is caused by your current version of Pytorch. I hope the alternative works out for you otherwise. Cheers!